# SQL Server 2012 join perfomance features?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

Consider a simple 3 table database i SQL Server 2012.

### Table A

```
AId
Name
Other1
Other2
```

### Table B

```
BId
Name
```

### Table A_B

```
BId
AId
```

### Simple example query:

```
SELECT TOP(20) A.Aid, A.Name, B.Bid, B.Name 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN A_B ON A.AId = A_B.Aid
INNER JOIN A as AA ON AA.Aid = A_B.Aid
INNER JOIN B ON B.BId = A_B.Bid
WHERE AA.Aid = @aid
AND A.Other1 = @other1
```

There are millions of rows in table A.
There are thousands of rows in table B.
There are ten times more rows in table A_B than A.
The Other1 and Other2 fields can be used to filter the queries.
Join queries using Top(20) could be done at a rate of 100 requests per second or more (specs are unclear).
The queries will almost always be using different parameters so result caching would not help that much.

**What features in SQL Server 2012 can help to improve join query perfomance given the example above?**

My initial thought is that since it's all PK int joins there isn't much that I could do. However I don't know if partitioned views could help.
I'm thinking that probably it's just about adding memory.

Comment: A very vague question. Indexes/Indexed Views.

Comment: How can improve the question?

Comment: Providing the actual queries would be a start.

Comment: Did you mean `AND B.Other1 = @other1`? Also, do you just need any `TOP 20`, or do you need the first 20 based on a particular order? How frequently does the data change? (A likely answer involves covering indexes, I'll probably upvote that when it gets posted.)

Comment: Also, how selective the data (i.e. ratio of rows in A to distinct values of Other1 in A)? For example, values of either "Male" or "Female" is not selective, 50 states across millions of rows is not very selectve, LastName could be pretty selective.

Comment: @PhilipKelley The query was wrong, thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected it. There will of course be different queries, but for now any top 20 will suffice.
The data won't change but continously grow.

Comment: Add tables and index, as asked please.

Comment: @PhilipKelley For the "other" columns there are *probably* float values where ranges are used to filter.

Comment: If you have a specific performance problem, then show us the table definitions and the query plan.

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's all just in the planning phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first thing to understand (well maybe not the first) is that a performance model is built into all current versions which is dependant on head seek times vs continuous reads, This may well change with solidstate drives. Your choice of clusted indexes will be important keeping likely frequently queried data together. Also having a covering index for each part of the query will mean that the data can be accessed without reading the table its self. Partitoning may help (but its probably a long way down the list). Keeping stats up do date is essential. To often poor performance comes from undermaintained indexes and stats. Actully all these things are true right back to SQL7 (except I dont think SQL7 had partitioned views). Having the right RAID structure can alter performace by a factor of 4. The number of tempdbs should be equivalent to the number of processors (upto about 16) and the tempdb load balancing option should be set to true. Having Tempdbs, logs and data distributed across diffent i/os. No auto shrink - its evil. These are the more obvious ones. If you really want to get to grips with large db, then "Inside SQL" by Kalen Delany is almost mandatory reading though probably costs more that a few GB of RAM. And as you said - more RAM.

Comment: Thank you! That was a lot to digest. :) I'll make sure I'll get that book.

Comment: Its the sort of thing those johnies over on SQL Stack have for breakfast but IMHO anyone designing dbSoftware should have more than a passing knowledge, so large merit points to you IMHO. Fell free to mark as the answer, my answer is just an encapulation of what others write books and charge big bucks for really understanding.

Comment: Little bit after the fact, but http://www.sswug.org/editorials/readed.aspx?id=2824 may prove a useful thread

Answer (score 1):

First yes have a clustered index for the PK

If Table B is smaller than Int16 use Int16
Not for disk space but for more rows in the same amount of memory

The interesting part is Table A_B
The order of that PK will probably effect in performance
Against just a single PK index which ever is second will be a slower join

Try the order each way
Check the query plan
Check the tuning adviser

My thought is
PK AId, BId
Non clustered index on BId based on that index is smaller

Then flop them around and compare
If the same then go with AId, BId for smaller index size and speed of insert

Then you can go into hints on the joins

Defrag on a regular basis

Insert in the order of the PK

If the data comes in natural order and insert speed is an issue then use that order for the PK

If insert speed is a problem then it may help to disable the non clustered index, insert, and then rebuild the non clustered index

Millions and thousands is still not enormous.

And I would not write the query like that
Keep the number joins down

```
SELECT TOP(20) A.Aid, A.Name, B.Bid, B.Name 
  FROM A_B 
  JOIN A  
    ON A.Aid = A_B.Aid
  JOIN B 
    ON B.BId = A_B.Bid
 WHERE AA.Aid = @aid
   AND A.Other1 = @other1
```

That query is very wasteful
Why join on all A.Aid = A_B.Aid to filter to a single AA.Aid in the where
Get the filter to execute early

This may perform better

```
SELECT TOP(20) A.Aid, A.Name, B.Bid, B.Name 
  FROM A_B 
  JOIN A  
    ON A.Aid = A_B.Aid
   AND A.Aid = @aid 
   AND A.Other1 = @other1
  JOIN B 
    ON B.BId = A_B.Bid
```

If you can get it to filter before it joins then less work
Check the query plan

A CTE on A with the conditions may coerce it to perform the filter first.

If you cannot get the filter to happen first with a single statement then create a #tempA with ID as a declared PK
(not a CTE the purpose is to materialize)

```
Insert into #tempA 
select Id, Name 
  from Table A 
 where A.Aid = @aid 
   AND A.Other1 = @other1
```

If Id is PK on Table A then that query returns 0 or 1 records
The join to #tempA is trivial

Comment: Thank you! You got me thinking about the joins, and actually I might be able to cut down to one join but making it an IN() query against A_B instead. I'll use the query analyzer and see how I can get the best execution path. Thanks!

Comment: You need data from A and B and you think you can cut it down to one join against Table A_B. Good luck.

Comment: Either I have written the query wrong, or you have misinterpreted it. Either way it doesn't matter, you got me thinking of different ways to solve it and I think i can have a lot of data already in memory and might be able to use a different set of parameters. You got me considering a plethora of new options which was the most valuable part for me, for which I'm truly grateful!